# Coq: Recursive definition of fibonacci is ill-formed

Tags: coq, fibonacci

I am trying to define Fibonacci numbers using coq. This is my code:

```
Fixpoint fibonacci (n:nat) : nat :=
       match n with
         | O => 1
         | S O => 1
         | S (S n') => fibonacci (S n') + fibonacci n
       end.
```

I met the error message:

> Recursive definition of fibonacci is ill-formed. In environment
> fibonacci : nat -> nat n : nat n0 : nat n' : nat Recursive call to
> fibonacci has principal argument equal to  "S n'" instead of one of
> the following variables:  "n0" "n'". Recursive definition is: "fun n :
> nat =>  match n with  | S (S n') => fibonacci (S n') + fibonacci n  |
> _ => 1  end".

I am wondering why this is wrong. Parenthetically, in the third clause of the match, I did not define the property of n' (e.g. n': nat), what would be the default of the property of n'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

All arguments of a recursive call must be structurally decreasing, that is you must strip away one constructor symbol in the match. In your case the (S n') argument is in fact structurally decreasing, but Coq doesn't detect that (which is a bit silly) because you add another constructor `S`, which is not allowed. The second argument is wrong and should probably be `n'`. Besides one usually defines this such that `fibonacci 0 = 0`.

To get around the issue of `(S n')` one gives it a separate name with `as` as in:

```
Require Import List.

Fixpoint fibonacci (n:nat) : nat :=
       match n with
         | O => 0
         | S O => 1
         | S (S O) => 1
         | S ((S n'') as n')=> fibonacci n' + fibonacci n''
       end.

Eval cbv in map fibonacci (seq 0 10).
```

Comment: Why do you need the `S (S 0) => 1` clause? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: Indeed, it is redundant, and nothing is lost if you remove it.

Comment: For me (personally) it would loose a bit of clearness because for me the Fibonacci sequence is defined as `fib(1)=1`, `fib(2)=1`, `fib(n)=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)`, and `0` is a sort of an extra case one can add (or must add for Coq `nat`). This might be a generation thing - I see that today many people define the Fibonacci sequence to start at 0. So I would consider leaving away this case as a technical optimization obscuring the definition, but I see that this is debatable.